# Getting items in GridView after it's been bound

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, user-controls, postback

I have a UserControl `AutomatedFeedGridView.ascx` which is essentially a GridView.  It has a public property `Category` which is passed in on the page using the control.

The problem I have is that I want to filter based on a dropdown list on the calling page.

Below is the codebehind for the `AutomatedFeedGridView` control:

```
// The feed category
public Feeds.FeedCategory Category { get; set; }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<AutomatedFeed> x = Feeds.GetAutomatedFeed(Category);
        gvAutomatedFeed.DataSource = x;
        gvAutomatedFeed.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        List<AutomatedFeed> x = (List<AutomatedFeed>)gvAutomatedFeedCategory.DataSource;

        foreach (AutomatedFeed y in x)
        {
            // if condition is not met, hide y
        }
    }
```

So on the first load, the GridView is bound to a List of `AutomatedFeed` objects.  On any subsequent calls (caused by a postback on the page containing the control) I want to run some code to filter out some of the items in the GridView.  The problem is this line:

```
List<AutomatedFeed> x = (List<AutomatedFeed>)gvAutomatedFeedCategory.DataSource;
```

I've tried all of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966755/gridview-remove-items) but none of them seem to work, I always get an *Object reference not set to an instance* error.  Am I missing something or am I doing this in completely the wrong way?

I know I could easily just make another call to `Feeds.GetAutomatedFeed(Category)` but there must be a better way to do it than to make another stored procedure call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store data source in session as `Session["x"] = x ;`

when page post back retrieve it back as  `List<AutomatedFeed> x =  List<AutomatedFeed>)Session["x"];`

**UPDATE:**

DataSource property will be null unless you explicitly re-assign and re-bind it on every postback.

You could use Session, Cache, or ViewState to keep the DataSource. But it will take more memory.

Comment: probably better to save it in the `ViewState`

Comment: Thanks, this is enough to solve my problem without having to re-execute the stored procedure.  I hadn't used `ViewState` programatically before. [This video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-save-and-load-view-state-information-for-a-custom-web-server-control) is simple but explains the basics in case anyone else is interested.

Answer (score 0):

The control is only generated and populated after the page.load, so it will not contain any data.